# 3nlogn -2n is Big Omega(nlogn)

Tags: complexity-theory

I am not able to justify that 3nlogn-2n is big omega.

I have tried putting in different values of c and n for trade off but in every case where n>=2 (n>=2 because if n<2 log n become 0 and c becomes 0) which is not true for, big omega as c>0. so in every case I tried to put in f(n)

f(n)>=cg(n) for 3nlogn-2n as state by my book and i am ending up with f(n)<=cg(n)

just need a guide line i know there must be a simple answer I am mixing up things with, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Big Omega is a lower bound, and in your case we have that (since n > nlogn)

```
3nlog(n) - 2n > 3nlog(n) - 2nlog(n) = nlog(n)
```

And we immediatly got that it's in `Omega(nlog(n))`